# Resize UIView after rotation transformation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, transform

I have added image view as subview in uiview. now i have rotated this image view using transformation. How can i resize the image view after the rotation transformation is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't resize manually, you should be setting the autoresizingMask of the view so that it is automatically resized when the rotation occurs

Comment: Yes but when i apply autoresizing mask, while rotating the image view becomes very large and out of bounds.

Comment: I'd say that you are using the wrong autoresizing mask. experiment with the possible options to see what works the best (thats pretty much what I do when dealing with autoresizing...)